# Include missing years in Group By query

Tags: sql, sql-server, missing-data

I am fairly new in Access and SQL programming. I am trying to do the following:

```
Sum(SO_SalesOrderPaymentHistoryLineT.Amount) AS [Sum Of PaymentPerYear]
```

and group by year even when there is no amount in some of the years. I would like to have these years listed as well for a report with charts. I'm not certain if this is possible, but every bit of help is appreciated.

My code so far is as follows:

```
SELECT
  Base_CustomerT.SalesRep,
  SO_SalesOrderT.CustomerId,
  Base_CustomerT.Customer,
  SO_SalesOrderPaymentHistoryLineT.DatePaid,
  Sum(SO_SalesOrderPaymentHistoryLineT.Amount) AS [Sum Of PaymentPerYear]

FROM
  Base_CustomerT
  INNER JOIN (
    SO_SalesOrderPaymentHistoryLineT
      INNER JOIN SO_SalesOrderT
        ON SO_SalesOrderPaymentHistoryLineT.SalesOrderId = SO_SalesOrderT.SalesOrderId
  ) ON Base_CustomerT.CustomerId = SO_SalesOrderT.CustomerId

GROUP BY
  Base_CustomerT.SalesRep,
  SO_SalesOrderT.CustomerId,
  Base_CustomerT.Customer,
  SO_SalesOrderPaymentHistoryLineT.DatePaid,
  SO_SalesOrderPaymentHistoryLineT.PaymentType,
  Base_CustomerT.IsActive

HAVING
  (((SO_SalesOrderPaymentHistoryLineT.PaymentType)=1)
  AND ((Base_CustomerT.IsActive)=Yes))

ORDER BY
  Base_CustomerT.SalesRep,
  Base_CustomerT.Customer;
```

Comment: You need another table with all years listed -- you can create this on the fly or have one in the db... join from that.

Comment: How do you want the result? Do you want to display years in ascending order (2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, ... 2015) with each year sales?

Comment: So `SO_SalesOrderPaymentHistoryLineT.DatePaid` is a year number?  I would have guessed it was a date, which will not get you per-year groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you John for your help. I found a solution which works for me. It looks quiet different but I learned a lot out of it. If you are interested here is how it looks now.

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW
  Base_Customer_RevenueYearQ.SalesRep,
  Base_Customer_RevenueYearQ.CustomerId,
  Base_Customer_RevenueYearQ.Customer,
  Base_Customer_RevenueYearQ.RevenueYear,
  CustomerPaymentPerYearQ.[Sum Of PaymentPerYear]
FROM
  Base_Customer_RevenueYearQ
  LEFT JOIN CustomerPaymentPerYearQ
    ON (Base_Customer_RevenueYearQ.RevenueYear = CustomerPaymentPerYearQ.[RevenueYear])
      AND (Base_Customer_RevenueYearQ.CustomerId = CustomerPaymentPerYearQ.CustomerId)
GROUP BY
  Base_Customer_RevenueYearQ.SalesRep,
  Base_Customer_RevenueYearQ.CustomerId,
  Base_Customer_RevenueYearQ.Customer,
  Base_Customer_RevenueYearQ.RevenueYear,
  CustomerPaymentPerYearQ.[Sum Of PaymentPerYear]
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another table with all years listed -- you can create this on the fly or have one in the db... join from that.  So if you had a table called alltheyears with a column called y that just listed the years then you could use code like this:

```
 WITH minmax as
 (
    select min(year(SO_SalesOrderPaymentHistoryLineT.DatePaid) as minyear,
           max(year(SO_SalesOrderPaymentHistoryLineT.DatePaid) as maxyear)
    from SalesOrderPaymentHistoryLineT
 ), yearsused as
 (
    select y
    from alltheyears, minmax
    where alltheyears.y >= minyear and alltheyears.y <= maxyear
 )
 select *
 from yearsused
 join ( -- your query above goes here! -- ) T 
    ON year(T.SO_SalesOrderPaymentHistoryLineT.DatePaid) = yearsused.y
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a data source that will provide the year numbers.  You cannot manufacture them out of thin air.  Supposing you had a table `Interesting_year` with a single column `year`, populated, say, with every distinct integer between 2000 and 2050, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
  base.SalesRep,
  base.CustomerId,
  base.Customer,
  base.year,
  Sum(NZ(data.Amount)) AS [Sum Of PaymentPerYear]

FROM
  (SELECT * FROM Base_CustomerT INNER JOIN Year) AS base
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM
    SO_SalesOrderT
    INNER JOIN SO_SalesOrderPaymentHistoryLineT
      ON (SO_SalesOrderPaymentHistoryLineT.SalesOrderId = SO_SalesOrderT.SalesOrderId)
  ) AS data
    ON ((base.CustomerId = data.CustomerId)
      AND (base.year = Year(data.DatePaid))),

WHERE
  (data.PaymentType = 1)
  AND (base.IsActive = Yes)
  AND (base.year BETWEEN
    (SELECT Min(year(DatePaid) FROM SO_SalesOrderPaymentHistoryLineT)
    AND (SELECT Max(year(DatePaid) FROM SO_SalesOrderPaymentHistoryLineT))

GROUP BY
  base.SalesRep,
  base.CustomerId,
  base.Customer,
  base.year,

ORDER BY
  base.SalesRep,
  base.Customer;
```

Note the following:

- The revised query first forms the Cartesian product of `BaseCustomerT` with `Interesting_year` in order to have base customer data associated with each year (this is sometimes called a `CROSS JOIN`, but it's the same thing as an `INNER JOIN` with no join predicate, which is what Access requires)
- In order to have result rows for years with no payments, you must perform an outer join (in this case a `LEFT JOIN`).  Where a (base customer, year) combination has no associated orders, the rest of the columns of the join result will be `NULL`.
- I'm selecting the CustomerId from Base_CustomerT because you would sometimes get a `NULL` if you selected from `SO_SalesOrderT` as in the starting query
- I'm using the Access `Nz()` function to convert `NULL` payment amounts to 0 (from rows corresponding to years with no payments)
- I converted your `HAVING` clause to a `WHERE` clause.  That's semantically equivalent in this particular case, and it will be more efficient because the `WHERE` filter is applied *before* groups are formed, and because it allows some columns to be omitted from the `GROUP BY` clause.
- Following Hogan's example, I filter out data for years outside the overall range covered by your data.  Alternatively, you could achieve the same effect without that filter condition and its subqueries by ensuring that table `Intersting_year` contains only the year numbers for which you want results.

Update: modified the query to a different, but logically equivalent "something like this" that I hope Access will like better.  Aside from adding a bunch of parentheses, the main difference is making both the left and the right operand of the `LEFT JOIN` into a subquery.  That's consistent with the consensus recommendation for resolving Access "ambiguous outer join" errors.

Comment: First of all thank you guys for your quick responds. John, I understand I have to create a new table with years but I can't get it to work with this LEFT JOIN. Error message is saying OUTER JOIN is too ambiguous.

Comment: Access's "Jet" SQL implementation is a bit ... peculiar ... and I'm not prepared to test against it.  I did update my answer with another cut at a specific query, however, with a view toward resolving the ambiguous outer join issue.

Comment: Thank you John for your help. I found a solution which works for me. It looks quiet different but I learned a lot out of it. If you are interested here is how it looks now.